Working with QGIS, cannot generate proper geoInformation for 3D terrain
I have generated contour polygon from raster (DEM) image. Now to see those terrain layer in 3D view, I converted the shpfiles to geojson and load those using maplibre gl web view. Now it is normal that over the contour layer, other layers like water, road, land will be visible but in 2D view it depends on layer adding sequence but for the case of this, the other layers than contour sit right below the contour layer. How to have visibility like the water layer will be over gradual on the contour layer. How can I do it. Cannot find any resource on doing this for vector data.
